# unable to use image_view with eletric

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I seem to have the same problem as described here
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/14394

I run uvc_cam and then try to view the image but end up with

```
  rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw
init done 
opengl support available 

(<unknown>:2222): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `(null)' in cast to `GtkWidget'

(<unknown>:2222): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type `(null)'

(<unknown>:2222): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

It works fine in diamondback. Any ideas?

Cheers,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11798/unable-to-use-image_view-with-eletric/) by [andreas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1031/andreas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2011-11-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-04**:
Sounds like a bug to me. Maybe in opencv2, perhaps in cv_bridge or image_view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Andreas,

This does look like a bug. Please [open a ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=image_pipeline&type=defect&&image_pipeline) to track it.

In your ticket include:

- What OS and version are you using?
- What desktop environment (Gnome/KDE/other?). In particular do you have Qt installed?
- Did you install image_pipeline with the Debian packages or from source?
- Likewise for OpenCV - did it come from the debs or did you build it yourself?

It looks like your OpenCV is using its new Qt backend for HighGUI, while image_view is wrongly assuming the GTK backend. This is a bug in image_view, but I don't understand why it's showing up - in our debs, OpenCV links against GTK but not Qt.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1031/andreas/) on 2011-11-08**:
Hi Patrick, thanks for the hint. I built OpenCV myself because I needed the GPU version of the libraries.  I now built them without Qt and it works. So it's no bug. Cheers